# MATLAB: Anova for non-linear model fits

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, anova

In Matlab, is there a quick way to perform an ANOVA on two non-linear model fits?  Similar to this R command:  http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/drc/html/anova.drc.html , used as:  anova(model2, model1).  The test I want, as specified in the link above, is:  "If two objects are specified a test for reduction from the larger to the smaller model is given. (This only makes statistical sense if the models are nested, that is: one model is a submodel of the other model.)"

I've only found this:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.anova.html  for linear models.

I'm using the fit() command to generate the fits so if I remember correctly the objects that hold the fit are of type 'cfit'